# Install SQL Server for a network of computers linked by a removable drive?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I need to install SQL Server to be used by multiple computers which have one removable drive in common, some computers use windows 7 while some uses windows 10. I tried to install SQL Server 2017 express on the shared removable drive from one of the computers but it says that it SQL 2017 Express are not allowed to install on a removable drive, and also that windows 7 doesn't support SQL Server 2017 express. What can I do to have a SQL Server that all the computers can share and access?

Comment: Use a network, or web interface is the usual normal way. or maybe localdb or another db

Comment: "What SQL server to use for accessing from multiple computers" is really not on-topic for SO (and pretty much all other SE sites as recommendation question). SQL express is generally only for local install - so you should be looking for either full MS SQL server or another DB Server of your choice...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Express Edition is perfectly acceptable as a network service. Perhaps you're thinking of Compact Edition or LocalDB?

Comment: @alroc you are right... need more coffee :) and read our own docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I think you misunderstand how SQL server works. Its not like a file system where all users need to look at the same file, its is a true server, which means it can run on any single machine, and the other machines connect via the server's address and known ports. Wherever its running needs to be powered on of course for the others to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @MichaelRandall and @TomC, install it on one of the Win 10 systems (or on any other Win 10 system) on a non removable storage. Access the DB via network from the other machines.

@AlexeiLevenkov posted a link to the appropriate documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: oh i see, but that computer that has the sql server installed on it has to be turned on for the other computers to access it right?